# Terraform: The condition expression must be of type bool

Tags: terraform

Variable.tf

```
home_region      = var.home_region
```

code.tf

```
resource compute abc

count = local.home_region ? 1 : 0

compartment_id = local.compute_comp_id
--
--
---
```

Error: Incorrect condition type

```
 on modules/compute/main.tf line 34, in resource "compute" "abc"   
  34:   count = local.home_region ? 1 : 0   
    |----------------   
    | local.home_region is "us-ashburn-1"   
   
The condition expression must be of type bool.
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you need to have some bool expression, such as:

```
count = local.home_region == "us-ashburn-1" ? 1 : 0
```

The expression will vary, depending on what you want to test for.